# Why is browser exit node different from Privoxy exit node?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, python, privoxy

I have Tor (bundle) browser and when I open this URL :

```
http://ipecho.net/plain
```

I get :

```
89.105.194.71
```

I set Privoxy in my Ubuntu to use Tor programmatically, but when I run my python code:

```
proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support) 
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
print opener.open('http://www.ipecho.net/plain').read()
```

I got :

```
171.25.193.235
```

Both IP addresses are exit nodes but why are the exit nodes different even they are using the same connection (I think)?

I ran them many times simultaneously they gave me different IP addresses.

My Privoxy setting (I've change these, others are commented):

```
forward-socks4a / 127.0.0.1:9150 .
listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118
```

The setting works fine with non-Tor browser.

Comment: Do you have a system-wide Tor daemon installed and also use Tor Browser? What are the exact settings you made in Privoxy?

Comment: @JensKubieziel I've download tor bundle, not system wide tor daemon. i will add my Privoxy setting to question,thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Tor does not use the same exit node for everything. The Tor Browser actually uses a security feature that makes sure it does not share the same circuits with any other program that uses the Tor client.